# Current flow trough capacitors at $t=0$

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, batteries

I'm bit confused about the current flow in capacitors. My question is, let's assume those two electric circuits:

[image]

As shown in the picture, the only difference is only the capacitance. I'm wondering about the current flow magnitude. In which of the circuits the current flow will be bigger? or will it be the same?
To start, I assume both plates of the capacitor are uncharged. My guess is that right at the moment of closing the switch before the capacitors are charged from the voltage source, the current flow will be even. Once they are fully charged, of course, the current will be bigger in the system with the bigger capacitor. But till this point, what will be the current flow?
thanks

Comment: hint: add a resistor in series with the switch, now solve the *same* question,that is find the turn-on current , then let $R \to 0$.

Comment: Rather than taking R to 0, if you want a physical solution, figure out what will really limit the current in your system --- is it the wire resistance, the battery's internal resistance, or the parasitic resistance of the capacitor itself (or do all three make significant contributions?). Then keep that resistance in your model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My guess is that right at the moment of closing the switch before the capacitors are charged from the voltage source, the current flow will be even.

At the moment after the switch closes, (and assuming we are observing the circuit with a time resolution crude enough that we don't see any effect from parasitic inductance in the circuit) the current is 100 V divided by $r$, where $r$ is the sum of all the parasitic resistances in the circuit (the wire resistance, the capacitor's parasitic resistance, the switch's parasitic resistance, the battery's internal resistance).

Therefore you are correct and the currents are equal in the two cases, assuming you have chosen two capacitors with equal parasitic resistance.

N.b.: If you have constructed your 100 uF capacitor by connecting ten 10-uF capacitors in parallel, then clearly you will not have the same parasitic resistance for the two cases.

> Once they are fully charged, of course, the current will be bigger in the system with the bigger capacitor.

Once the capacitors are fully charged, the current goes to 0 in both cases. This is more or less the definition of "fully charged".

With real world capacitors you might also need to consider the leakage current of the capacitors. This is likely higher for the higher-valued capacitor, but you should not assume it is without considering the actual specifications of the components you are comparing.